# Hamachi² configuration file... Where is it?

Tags: 10.10, configuration, vpn

I recently installed [hamachi²](https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi2/) and haguichi on my 10.10 machine.
It works, but it loses its connection every few minutes and I have to reconnect.

I looked into this, and apparently I need to set the KeepAlive in the configuration file to 100. This shouldn't be a hard task, so I looked for the hamachi directory.
I checked the obvious place: `/home/username/.hamachi` ... but this directory doesn't exist. (Yes, I did enable hidden files.)

After doing a file search for hamachi, it returned nothing either. I'm in the dark here, what am I missing?

Comment: How did you install it (or from where)?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use Haguichi, this is a GUI for Hamachi.

See:
http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/install-hamachi2-and-haguichi-gui-for.html

I have seen the .DEB file, it creates files in

-/opt

-/etc

-/usr

Take a look @ /opt/logmein-hamachi/bin

Comment: This technically doesn't answer the question. I couldn't find the config file in any of those directories (haguichi also fails with an error)